# Scala - Create a List of case objects that extend an sealed abstract class

Tags: scala, sealed, companion-object

I'm trying to create a List of case objects in a companion object. The objects all inherit from a sealed abstract class. But the compiler is saying "not found: value CompositeSpectrum" and so on for each item in the List. The sealed class and case objects all compile fine, it's just when I try to make the List in the companion object that I get errors.

```
sealed abstract class Peculiarity(val abbreviation: String, val description: String) {
    case object CompositeSpectrum extends Peculiarity("comp", "composite spectrum")
    case object NebularFeaturesPresent extends Peculiarity("neb", "nebular features present")
    case object ShellStar extends Peculiarity("sh", "shell star")
    case object Uncertainty extends Peculiarity(":", "uncertainty")
    case object VariableSpectralFeatures extends Peculiarity("var", "variable spectral features")
    case object WeakFeatures extends Peculiarity("wl", "weak features")
    case object VeryBroadAbsorptionFeatures extends Peculiarity("nn", "very broad absorption features")
    case object BroadAbsorptionFeatures extends Peculiarity("n", "broad absorption features")
    case object EmissionLinesPresent extends Peculiarity("e", "emission lines present")
    case object NIIIandHEIIEmission extends Peculiarity("f", "NIII and HeII emission (O stars)")
    case object EnhancedMetalFeatures extends Peculiarity("m", "enhanced metal features")
    case object OtherPeculiarity extends Peculiarity("p", "other peculiarity")
    case object VeryNarrowAbsorptionLines extends Peculiarity("s", "very narrow absorption lines")
}

object Peculiarity {
    val peculiarities = List[Peculiarity](
        CompositeSpectrum,
        NebularFeaturesPresent,
        ShellStar,
        Uncertainty,
        VariableSpectralFeatures,
        WeakFeatures,
        VeryBroadAbsorptionFeatures,
        BroadAbsorptionFeatures,
        EmissionLinesPresent,
        NIIIandHEIIEmission,
        EnhancedMetalFeatures,
        OtherPeculiarity,
        VeryNarrowAbsorptionLines)
}
```

Comment: I should mention that my objective here is to iterate over the List at runtime. I will have a need to pattern match as well, but I also need to iterate over the list while parsing a text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because those objects don't exist unless they are referenced from an instance of the type of `Peculiarity` because they are declared as internal objects to `Peculiarity`.

```
val pec = new Peculiarity("","") {}
val peculiarities = List[Peculiarity](
  pec.CompositeSpectrum,
  pec.NebularFeaturesPresent,
  ...
```

But I doubt that what you after, you can just move the declaration to outside the abstract class

```
  sealed abstract class Peculiarity(val abbreviation: String, val description: String)
  case object CompositeSpectrum extends Peculiarity("comp", "composite spectrum")
  case object NebularFeaturesPresent extends Peculiarity("neb", "nebular features present")
  ...
```

And then your declaration would work just fine.

Comment: Thanks, both answers were correct, but this one explains why my code wasn't working as well.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to nest the `case object`s inside the sealed abstract class.

This compiles for me.

```
sealed abstract class Peculiarity(val abbreviation: String, val description: String)
case object CompositeSpectrum extends Peculiarity("comp", "composite spectrum")
case object NebularFeaturesPresent extends Peculiarity("neb", "nebular features present")
case object ShellStar extends Peculiarity("sh", "shell star")
case object Uncertainty extends Peculiarity(":", "uncertainty")
case object VariableSpectralFeatures extends Peculiarity("var", "variable spectral features")
case object WeakFeatures extends Peculiarity("wl", "weak features")
case object VeryBroadAbsorptionFeatures extends Peculiarity("nn", "very broad absorption features")
case object BroadAbsorptionFeatures extends Peculiarity("n", "broad absorption features")
case object EmissionLinesPresent extends Peculiarity("e", "emission lines present")
case object NIIIandHEIIEmission extends Peculiarity("f", "NIII and HeII emission (O stars)")
case object EnhancedMetalFeatures extends Peculiarity("m", "enhanced metal features")
case object OtherPeculiarity extends Peculiarity("p", "other peculiarity")
case object VeryNarrowAbsorptionLines extends Peculiarity("s", "very narrow absorption lines")

object Peculiarity {
  val peculiarities = List[Peculiarity](
      CompositeSpectrum,
      NebularFeaturesPresent,
      ShellStar,
      Uncertainty,
      VariableSpectralFeatures,
      WeakFeatures,
      VeryBroadAbsorptionFeatures,
      BroadAbsorptionFeatures,
      EmissionLinesPresent,
      NIIIandHEIIEmission,
      EnhancedMetalFeatures,
      OtherPeculiarity,
      VeryNarrowAbsorptionLines)
}
```